# what these suffixes mean,-coel,-blast,-cyst?

Tags: histology, bone-biology

in the connective tissue (Bones) we have 3 types  osteoblast, osteocoel,osteocyst what are they and why they differ.

Comment: have you tried searching the net for the answer. Wikipedia might be able to answer this question.

Comment: `-blast` : A precursor/progenitor/immature cell..
`-coel` : A fluid filled cavity...
`cyst` : A clump of cells with a defined boundary...

Comment: @WYSIWYG - even if it's short, please post answers to questions as actual answers. Comments should just be used to clarify the question, not answer it. See [this meta topic](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/552/comments-with-answers) for a discussion regarding this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @MattDMo: thanks for clarification.. I'll take care.. Since this question is closed, i won't be able to convert this one

Answer (score 2):

You can easily search this on the web.

Osteoblasts are the immature cells of bone which are responsible for the production and mineralization of bone matrix.

Osteocytes are the mature cells of bone found in open spaces in bone called lacunae. The functions of osteocytes includes maintenance of bone and  calcium homeostasis.

Osteoclasts are responsible for removal of bone.

Source : Tortora and Derrickson